# Google Translate API <span class="notranslate"> in title

Tags: php, api, google-translate

I have a problem with the Google Translate API, I cannot exclude elements in the title tag from being translated, and I am not reading anything that contraindicates in the documentation

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title <span class="notranslate">{page_name}</span></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Título &lt;span class = &quot;notranslate&quot;&gt; {page_name} &lt;/span&gt;</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Hola</p>
   </body>
</html>
```